# returning command line from windows tasklist

Tags: r, windows, tasklist

I am searching for a command to get the command line written in the windows task manager. I was using `tasklist /fo CSV /v` but it doesn't provide the command line I get when I look at the task manager. I attach a picture to show what I mean, it is the right most column.

[image: Task-Manager]

I need this information in a system call within `r`.

Comment: i dont think `tasklist` returns the executable path. you need `wmic process`

Comment: `wmic process where name="MaxQuantTask.exe" get commandline`

Comment: I am not happy with installing a different tool. Isn't there a way to extract the commandline information via the process ID?

Comment: `wmic` is in windows command line. try running eryksun's comment or run this `wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath`. see also https://superuser.com/questions/1078734/wmic-in-for-loop

Comment: ahhhhh, I tried to use `wmic` before but windows wasn't autocompleting like in Linux so I was expecting it isn't installed :-) Thanks, this works as expected!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness:

```
#get list of processes' ids and exec paths
res <- system("wmic process get ProcessID,CommandLine", intern=TRUE)

#parse the results to get a nice data.frame
ans <- trimws(res)[!grepl("^[0-9]", trimws(res))]
ans <- ans[ans!=""][-1]
data.frame(
    ProcessId=sapply(strsplit(ans, " "), tail, n=1L),
    CommandLine=sapply(strsplit(ans, " "), function(x) trimws(paste(head(x, n=-1L), collapse=" ")))
)
head(df)
```

Comment: Note that the command line is a Unicode string, and wmic's Unicode handling is annoying. It uses a lossy OEM encoding when writing to a pipe or console and UTF-16 when writing to a file. I don't know R, but I assume the results here are parsed by redirecting wmic's output to a pipe, in which case the command line will be encoded as OEM, and any characters that aren't in that set of about 250 characters will be best-fit mapped to another character or "?". For example, if OEM is codepage 437, then "β" => "ß" (i.e. Greek small-letter Beta becomes Latin small-letter Sharp S).

Comment: If this matters, then you need to redirect the output to a temporary file, which will be Unicode (UTF-16 encoded).

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for all the improvements and comments! hopefully OP is not facing all these issues. if yes, we can always `>` the output into a file