# R function to determine if another application is running

Tags: r

I have an R script that reads a file from my synced OneDrive folder. The file contains data from a remote computer that is updated hourly. I run the R script daily. Sometimes I forget to open OneDrive to sync files before I run the R script. **How do I ask R from within my script if OneDrive (or another software) is running?** Using Windows 7/10 and the R 3.5.1.

**Also, is there a generalized command to determine from within an R script whether application XYZ is running?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows run this.  If OneDrive is running then `task` will contain a line of information having the substring `OneDrive.exe`; otherwise, that substring will not be present.

```
task <- shell('tasklist /fi "imagename eq OneDrive.exe" /nh /fo csv', intern = TRUE)
grepl("OneDrive.exe", task) # returns TRUE if OneDrive running; else FALSE
```

This can be generalized by factoring out the image name:

```
imageName <- "OneDrive.exe" # change this line
cmd <- sprintf('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %s" /nh /fo csv', imageName)
task <- shell(cmd, intern = TRUE)
grepl(imageName, task)
```

Alternately use `schtasks` instead of `tasklist`, use `taskscheduler_ls()` in the taskscheduleR package or see [returning command line from windows tasklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48901500/returning-command-line-from-windows-tasklist) .